# Can't install TensorFlow version 1 in python3

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I want to install TensorFlow version 1. I used this command

```
conda install tensorflow 1.4
```

But it said the following packages are not available from this channel.

Answer (score 0):

use below pip command to install

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31077 This link has good explaination about that.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is available from the [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) channel.

You can install TensorFlow version 1.13 with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

or if it has to be version 1.4 (which has a dependency of Python 2.7, 3.5 or 3.6):

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.4
```

will work. The installation of 1.13 won't work on Python 3.8 as the dependency list is:

```
 - tensorflow -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|3.7.*']
```